# Foreach Mediator WSO2

Tags: wso2-esb

im new with WSO2 tools, i want asking something with Foreach Mediator. The plan was transform the request json message when testing with postman to xml format. i was success with single fixed length json request transform to xml format. And now im using Foreach Mediator for process many fixed length json.

My Code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/dm4" name="DataMapper4" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <foreach expression="//InformationBankAccount/Accounts" id="itr1">
                <sequence>
                    <property expression="json-eval($.InformationBankAccount.Accounts.InputInformation)" name="Info" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <Accounts xmlns="">
                                <NumberAccount>$1</NumberAccount>
                                <AccountName>$2</AccountName>
                                <AccountPhoneNumber>$3</AccountPhoneNumber>
                            </Accounts>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="substring($ctx:Info,1,8)"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="translate(substring($ctx:Info,9,10),' ','')"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="translate(substring($ctx:Info,19,12),' ','')"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

My Result On PostMan

```
    <jsonObject>
    <InformationBankAccount>
        <Accounts>
            <NumberAccount/>
            <AccountName/>
            <AccountPhoneNumber/>
        </Accounts>
        <Accounts>
            <NumberAccount/>
            <AccountName/>
            <AccountPhoneNumber/>
        </Accounts>
    </InformationBankAccount>
</jsonObject>
```

Edit:
Sample Request Json

```
{
      "InformationBankAccount":{
         "Accounts":
            {
                "InputInformation":"10082022HitoshiNAG085688001530"
            },
            "Accounts":
            {
                "InputInformation":"10099999HitoshiNAG085688001530"
            }
      }
}
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `Info` property not correctly, for your example. Change `Info` to this:

`<property name="Info" expression="json-eval($.Accounts.InputInformation)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

or this

`<property name="Info" expression="$body/Accounts/InputInformation/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

In ForEach Mediator, you are 'inside' the `InformationBankAccount`, so this node is no longer valid.

Comment: thank you sir. Its working now. And i learn with new things about foreach